# Chat messages template

Tags: html, css

hi guys I am working on a chat and now I have to deal with generating messages, mostly I have problems with CSS, becuase I want to have 3 divs inside of message div (author, text and time), and what you can see is that when text is too long, then text and date goes down, and it looks awkward, I was trying to set up it with absolute position, but I think there's a better way to fix it.

Can you give me some directions what should I do?

this is how it looks like
http://jsbin.com/iPaYete/1/

Comment: What is wrong with the absolute position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iPaYete/3)
you need to change your **css like this**:

```
    p { margin:0; padding:0}
    .message {
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
    }

    .author {
        color: blue; 
        margin-left: 20px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        height: auto; 
        float: left;
    }

    .text {
        /*float: left; */
        margin-left: 90px;
        margin-right: 90px;
    }

    .time {
        vertical-align: top; 
        margin-right: 20px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-size: 0.8em; 
        float: right;
    }

    .line {
        width: 80%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        clear: both;

    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**And HTMl like this:**

```
<div class="message">
    <div class="author">
        <p>guest1:</p>
    </div>
  <div class="time">
        <p>11:20:12<br />27/12/2013</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Hello, can you tell me something about English language?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="line">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <div class="author">
        <p>guest234:</p>
    </div>
  <div class="time">
        <p>11:21:41<br />27/12/2013</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>English is a West Germanic language that was first spoken in early medieval England and is now the most widely used language in the world.[4] It is spoken as a first language by the majority populations of several sovereign states, including the United Kingdom, the United States, Canada, Australia, Ireland, New Zealand and a number of Caribbean nations. It is the third-most-common native language in the world, after Mandarin Chinese and Spanish.[5] It is widely learned as a second language and is an official language of the European Union, many Commonwealth countries and the United Nations, as well as in many world organisations.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="line">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you :)
and btw. is it possible, to set author and date center on x,y? Because as you can see if I have longer text, then author and date are on the top, but should be on the middle of div, but both don't have set up height, because here height can't be static, is there a way to do something with it? I mean I know, that I need height to set <p> on the middle of div, but what if we don't have height?

Comment: Hahahahaa .. then again you need to restructure like this: http://jsbin.com/iPaYete/4/